# React onClose eventListener not fired on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried to use [react-dialog-polyfill](https://github.com/woofers/react-dialog-polyfill/blob/master/src/modal.js), but when I test my code, I knew that the onClose event listener was not fired on Safari, even though it worked on Chrome. Below is the code in react-dialog-polyfill.

```
import dialogPolyfill from 'dialog-polyfill';
const ModalBase = forwardRef((p, modal) => {
  const {
    children,
    open,
    ready,
    onCancel,
    onClose,
    useAsModal,
    ...rest
  } = p
  useEffect(() => {
    const self = modal.current

    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(self)
    if (!self || !ready || self.open === open) return
    const show = useAsModal ? () => self.showModal() : () => self.show()
    const close = () => self.close()
    const action = open ? show : close
    action()
  }, [ready, open, modal, useAsModal])
  const onCancelWrap = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onCancel(e, modal.current)
  }
  const onCloseWrap = e => {
    onClose(e, modal.current)
  }
  return (
    <dialog {...rest}
     ref={modal}
     onCancel={onCancelWrap}
     onClose={onCloseWrap}
    >
      {children}
    </dialog>
  )
})
```

Then I discovered that when I comment out the onCancel and onClose part below:

```
return (
    <dialog {...rest}
     ref={modal}
     //onCancel={onCancelWrap}
     //onClose={onCloseWrap}
    >
      {children}
    </dialog>
  )
```

and add native event listener,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const self = modal.current
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(self);
    self.onclose=e => {
      onClose(e, self)
    }
    self.oncancel=e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      onCancel(e, self)
    }
```

it worked.

I think it is the problem that react doesn't call onClose `<dialog onClose={onClose} />`

Is this a problem of React?

Comment: Safari doesn't support the `<dialog>` tag, most likely what's causing the issue

Comment: I knew that, so I used polyfill: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/dialog-polyfill .

Also, When I was using this polyfill without React, it worked so I'm sure that this polyfill is not causing this problem.

Comment: I solved the problem, so I changed the post a little bit.